# loading jars during splash screen

Tags: javafx, splash-screen, jar-signing

I have a main application which is referencing to 4-5 external jar files. So while compiling the project netbeans ide(javafx application) takes long time. Therefore I want to design a splash screen and which will be displayed till all jars gets loaded.

My JNLP file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="Black.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>Black</title>
    <vendor>RATTAN</vendor>
    <description>Sample JavaFX 2.0 application.</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.2+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="Black.jar" size="3393158" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/commons-io-1.3.2.jar" size="95655" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/commons-lang-2.0.jar" size="179420" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/newlink.jar" size="6160" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/scribe-1.3.0.jar" size="74543" download="eager" />
  </resources>
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
  <applet-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback"  name="Black" >
    <param name="requiredFXVersion" value="2.2+"/>
  </applet-desc>
  <jfx:javafx-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="test.Test"  name="Black" />
  <update check="always"/>
</jnlp>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use preloaders module from JavaFx

here is complete tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/preloaders.htm

Good luck,'.